# SAML assertion fails

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml, okta, spring-security-saml2

I have a Spring-SAML app with Okta as IDP. I'm doing IDP initiated flow and 
get this exception :

```
org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Endpoint with message binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST and URL https://<myCompanyUrl>.com/saml/SSO wasn't found in local metadata
```

When I look at my local metadata I see:

```
 <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                 Location="https://<server IP address> :<server port>/saml/SSO" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
```

Looks like it is trying to match a URL containing a hostname to a URL with a server IP address. The location field is auto-generated. Does anybody know what configuration option affects this?

---

**UPDATE 1**

here is my metadataGeneratorFilter config :

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="entityId" value="https://myHostname/myApp"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Looks like there is an option in general SAML setting in Okta called Single Sign on URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right mystery solved:

Per Spring-SAML documentation , when you are in a reverse-proxy / load balancer set up  you have to make sure to specify

```
<property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://www.myserver.com/spring-security-saml2-sample"/>
```

See [SPRING-SAML documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-authentication-assertion)
10.1 Reverse proxies and load balancers